# Почему в Blender не видно текстур на объектах, а только вершины?

Tags: 3d, blender

Здравствуйте я только начал изучать blender и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Изучая blender у меня почему-то перестали быть видны материалы объектов. Как снова сделать их видимыми. Примерно так:
[image]

[image: Картинка в Blender]

Comment: z -> material preview

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
2. <kbd>Z</kbd> - material preview

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Z

Нужно выбрать объект и нажать эту комбинацию клавиш, она делает объекты прозрачными.